# Passando variável javascript para php ou direto para um campo

Tags: php, javascript

Como passar o resultado deste script para um campo e ja retornando formatado em Moeda Real

```
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" id="iv"/></br>
<input type="text" id="campo" value="10"></br>
<select name="children-qnt" id="children-qnt">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option selected value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
Result: <span id="resultado">10</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var $campo = byId('campo'),
$select= byId('children-qnt'),
$checkbox = byId('iv');

function byId(element){
return document.getElementById(element);
}

function updateResult(){
var result =  parseInt($campo.value) *
            parseInt($select.value);
byId('resultado').innerHTML = $checkbox.checked ? result * 2 : result;


}

$campo.addEventListener('keyup', updateResult);
$select.addEventListener('change', updateResult);
$checkbox.addEventListener('change', updateResult);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não estou certo de sua pergunta, mas se quiser passar o valor de uma variável JS para o PHP você pode utilizar AJAX.

AJAX sem jQuery: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#post

Sobre passar o valor para um campo, o seu Script já faz isso, ele passa o valor para o campo `<span id="resultado"><!-- valor que fica aqui vem via script --></span>`.

Acrescentei um teste para quando ele não digitar nada no input id="campo" e coloquei o método de formar para reais no script.

http://jsfiddle.net/kovLtn9k/1/

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Ok era isso mesmo que eu precisava mais não esta somando as ultimas casas decimais e quando eu coloco id no campo não aparece por nada exe: <input type="text id="resultado" />

Comment: Você não pode e nem deve colocar dois id's iguais na mesma página, e o id="resultado" você já tem e como o seu script está usando ele, pode e dará conflito!

Sobre o fato de ele não estar somando as casas decimais, isso acontece pelo comando `parseInt`, pois você está dizendo para ele pegar somente os inteiros do valor, ou seja, se tens 10,50 ele irá pegar o inteiro 10!